# Why am I getting null in my axios request on response.data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

This is the Node.ts route for the api

```
app.get('/getCrop/:id' , async (req , res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  
  const filters = {
    entity : id
  }

  const cropDetails = await CropInfo.findOne(filters)

  console.log(cropDetails)

  res.send({cropDetails})
})
```

The frontend where i use axios to call API

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getCrop/:id" , {
        withCredentials: true
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
  } , [])
```

In the backend when I console.log(cropDetails) I get the following

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62e044a52e794ca03ffa823d"),
  entity: '56157542',
  diseaseName: 'Fungi',
  probability: 99.3,
  diseaseCause: null,
  diseaseDescription: 'Fungi take energy from the plants on which they live, causing damage to the plant. Fungal infections are responsible for approximately two-thirds of infectious plant diseases and cause wilting, molding, rusts, scabs, rotted tissue, and other problems.',
  biologicalTreatment: [
    'If possible remove and destroy the infected parts of the plant (burn it, toss it into the garbage, or bury it deeply). Do not compost.',
    'Apply ecological products for plant protection (e.g. neem oil, baking soda, soap).'
  ],
  chemicalTreatment: [ 'If necessary, apply a fungicide.' ],
  prevention: [
    'Use resistant species and cultivars as well as healthy, certified seeds and seedlings.',
    'Avoid overwatering. Ensure having good soil drainage.',
    'Improve the air circulation around the plant.',
    'Avoid prolonged wetting of the leaves - avoid overhead irrigation.',
    'Rotate crops. Avoid planting sensitive crops in infested soil.',
    'Disinfect tools and hands to avoid disease transmission.'
  ],
  image: 'https://plant.id/media/images/da5fd4583a614a9197cb76d25693362e.jpg',
  plantTrue: 'true',
  is_healthy: 'false',
  __v: 0
}
```

however when I res.send the data to the frontend , On res.data , I get null meaning no data, am i doing something wrong? I appreciate any help in advance, Thank you

Comment: Can you try `res.json({ cropDetails })`? Also, `"http://localhost:4000/getCrop/:id"` looks wrong, because there is no id set (just the path parameter `:id`)?.

Comment: Still null , what makes it look wrong? Maybe that might be the issue

Comment: You need something like `http://localhost:4000/getCrop/62e044a52e794ca03ffa823d` (your actual id). Also add a `try`-/`catch`-statement around `findOne` in order to log errors.

Comment: @pzaenger When I added a try and catch , in the console for the backend , It showed me the data and showed me another console saying null. Seems like both the try and catch run

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the response to the front end, from the route add a return like this: `return res.send({cropDetails})`

Comment: Still getting null